# How is a function defined that contains a log of a number that can get negative?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, graphing-functions

I came across a problem on Khan Academy that was about finding the graph of a transformed function. The (transformed) function is given by:

$$y = 3 \log_2(2 - x)$$

What I don't understand, how can this function definition be valid for values $x > 2$? Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but isn't $\log_b x$ only defined for $b, x > 0$ and $b \neq 1$

[image]

Comment: If you allow your answers to become complex then there aren't any problems.

Comment: In the correct answer, it is not valid for $x>2$ I think, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I have misunderstood your difficulty, but I think you have answered your own question.  Indeed, as long as we are concerned with real numbers, $3\log_2(2-x)$ is not defined for $x>2$.  But the graph you have posted has no points on it for $x>2$, so there is no problem.

Minor extra point: $3\log_2(2-x)$ is also undefined for $x=2$.

Comment: Ah yeah, you are right, I really missed that. I didn't look closer at the correct solution then, but it indeed doesn't have any points for $x>2$. That makes it clear for me then, thanks for helping me to see that.